# magento 2 rest api accessing products based on store code giving same products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

I'm using below url to access products which are specific to store

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/products/product_name
```

but in output, i can see all other products as well. What may be the error or did I missed anything in a parameter.

Comment: did u get the solution for this ? please let me know i am looking for the the solution thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with magento rest api, looks they have problem in core (And they didn't fix this problem yet).. But I found solution with filters, you can filter by website_id (Please set website_id in filter no website_ids) and rest api will filter result by website_id).

Example code is here
In this case I set website_id = 2

```
    https://your-site/rest/all/V1/products/?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=website_id&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you customized anything because by default magento never return any product when filtered by product name. You can refer 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html

It filters by sku. Please review your question once more or provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, looks like it can also be resolved by adding `store_id` to the search criteria. e.g:

```
https://<DOMAIN>/rest/<STORE_CODE>/V1/products?searchCriteria=&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=<STORE_ID>
```

Or if website is enough use Dario's answer